# Does stationarity under ADF test imply mean, variance and covariance stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

Newbie question. I am reading about stationary series and understand that it has many forms:

- mean stationary
- variance stationary
- covariance stationary

If I run an augmented dicky fuller test and find that the series is stationary is that sufficient to say that the series is stationary in all respects?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104801/42371 I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Rejecting the null hypothesis of a unit root after applying the ADF test does not imply that the series is stationary in all respects. The ADF test is devised to detect non-stationarity in the long-term cycle, i.e. the trend of the series. Non-stationarity in other cycles are not inspected by this test. As long as the series exhibits a stationary trend pattern, sources of non-stationarity such as 
a changing seasonal pattern or a switch in the variance of the series will most likely result in rejecting the null hypothesis of the ADF test.